# Using NSLayoutConstraints to align dynamic views vertically within a ScrollView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have an application which has a view that is dynamically generated and can be different every time the view loads. The main view contains a ScrollView set to the bounds of the main view. Subviews are then added dynamically to the ScrollView, but the heights of these views will not be the same and they can change heights at any time (eg. user clicks contents of view and it changes). I want to use layout constraints to make sure each view stays aligned to the one above it with some arbitrary padding. See the image below:

[image: needed layout]

Right now all padding values are set to 10 (top, left, and right). I am setting the positions of these subviews manually using their frames but this does not work if the views change size, so I want to change this to use the NSLayoutConstraints, but I am running into some issues.

As a test I set the subview's frame like I did before, but then I added the constraint:

```
// newView is created and its frame is initialized
self.scrlView?.addSubview(newView)
let constr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.previousView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
NSLayoutConstraints.activateConstraints([constr])
newView.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.previousView = newView
```

But the views are nowhere to be seen. What am I doing wrong? All that is needed is to make sure the tops of each view are aligned below the previous view and that they stay that way regardless of the view heights.

Also,  since these views are all added to a scrollview, with using the layout constraints above how do I set the correct content size of the scroll view?

Comment: I can see the top constraint but where are the leading and trailing (a.k.a left and right) constraints for newView?

Comment: @gwinyai Are they needed? Really all I care about are the top alignments.

Comment: My assumption at this point is that the content view of the scroll view is not adjusting to fit your subviews. You could 1. adjust the content size manually as follows self.scrlView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height) or 2. give the subviews at the minimum a top and  left constraint.

Comment: @gwinyai The scrollview is set with scrlView?.frame = GCRectMake(0,0,view.frame.width,view.frame.height) , I just tried adding the left constraint (and right) as follows but has the same issue: let constrl = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.scrlView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

Comment: Yes sure, but did you also try my first suggestion as follows self.scrlView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height) I am not worried about the scollView's frame. Adjusting the scroll view's frame will not adjust its content view.

Comment: @gwinyai Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. I also forced the contentsize to the main view's frame as suggested (also doubled the content height just to be sure)

Comment: You're going to make your life easier if you use a vertical stack view inside that scrollview. You can set the padding for it, constrain it's width so it has the side padding. And it will manage the constraints for you. Your dynamic views just have to have a height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want something like this:

[image: demo]

Setting the content size of the scroll view with autolayout is explained in [Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html). To summarize, autolayout sets the `contentSize` of the scroll view based on the constraints between the scroll view and its descendant views. This means:

- You need to create constraints between the scroll view and its descendant views so the scroll view's `contentSize` will be set correctly.
- You need to create constraints between the tiles (the colored views in your picture) and the main view (which is the superview of the scroll view) to set the width of the tiles correctly. Constraints from a tile to its enclosing scroll view **cannot** set the size of the tile—only the `contentSize` of the scroll view.

For any view you create in code, if you intend to use constraints to control its size or position, you also need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Otherwise the autoresizing mask will interfere with the behavior of your explicit constraints.

Here's how I made the demo. I used a `UIButton` subclass that, when tapped, toggles its own height between 60 and 120 points:

```
class HeightTogglingButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightConstraint = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
        heightConstraint.isActive = true
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(HeightTogglingButton.toggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @IBAction func toggle(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { 
            self.heightConstraint.constant = 180 - self.heightConstraint.constant
            self.window?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    private(set) var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

Then I laid out ten of these buttons in a scroll view. I set up constraints to control the width of each button, and the layout of each button relative to the other buttons. The top and bottom buttons are constrained to the top and bottom of the scroll view, so they control `scrollView.contentSize.height`. All buttons are constrained to the leading and trailing edges of the scroll view, so they all jointly control `scrollView.contentSize.width`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)])

        let margin: CGFloat = 10

        var priorAnchor = scrollView.topAnchor
        for i in 0 ..< 10 {
            let button = HeightTogglingButton()
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(i) / 10, saturation: 0.8, brightness: 0.3, alpha: 1)
            button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
            scrollView.addSubview(button)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -2 * margin),
                button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: margin),
                button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -margin),
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priorAnchor, constant: margin)])
            priorAnchor = button.bottomAnchor
        }

        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priorAnchor, constant: margin).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Just so I am clear before I try to implement this, I have other subviews in the scollview that I was not assigning constraints to, is this why the views that I did assign constraints to would not show up on the view? Also, the subviews I am adding are custom views that also have subviews, do these also need constraints or can I leave those positioned how I have previously laid them out? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to position a subview directly by setting its frame, that's ok. Just avoid creating any explicit constraints on it.

Comment: This seems to work for items that don't resize but as soon as a view resizes it doesn't adjust the other views and they stay in their last position. I am only adding the constraints you suggested to the subviews (no subviews of the subviews are changed, those are all adjusted with frames). I am using Swift 2 so I had to make some changes to the code but I do not see why that would be a problem. (eg using activateConstraints() and constraintEqualToAnchor()). For a resizing example I use self.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(self.frame.height).active=true after setting the new frame height

Comment: It sounds like you are creating a new height constraint each time you want to resize a view. That won't work. If there's an existing height constraint for the view, you need to modify its constant. That's what my `HeightTogglingButton` does.

Comment: You are correct. That is exactly what I was doing. I was in the middle of typing that as a response to you when you commented back. It all seems to be working now! Thank you very much!